# MongoDB Spark Connector not working on Windows

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark

I am using MongoDB-Spark Connector on Windows.I have Spark installend in C drive in C:/Spark.
I have clone MongoDB Spark connector in using following command in c drive -

git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark.git

and mongo-spark folder is created in C drive.

When I am running following command in Spark bin folder -

```
C:\spark\bin>spark-shell --conf "spark.mongodb.input.uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.CoOrder?readPreference=primaryPreferred" --conf "spark.mongodb.output.uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.CoOrder1" --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:1.1.0
```

There is fllowing error -

> 'C:\spark\bin\spark-shell2.cmd" --conf "spark.mongodb.input.uri' is
>   not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or
>   batch file.

How can I connect spark with MongoDB?
Here my spark is not connectoed to mongo-spark folder.How can I link spark with mongo-spark folder?

Thanks

Comment: C:\spark\bin>spark-shell --help output?  It may be that passing configuration flags to windows isnt currently supported.  You can either set them as part of your actual configuration or pass the uri's as options once in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

The error is generally related to incomplete installation of Apache Spark on Windows. Ensure that you can first execute `spark-shell` command on it's own to get a Spark Scala shell.

Note that you do not need to clone `mongo-spark` git repository to use MongoDB Spark Connector, the spark-shell option `--packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_` will download the necessary jars from maven central.

See also [MongoDB Spark Connector](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/)